# Data undefined in first call?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I created this function, that returns me an object with mapped values.
I have a problem, the second map is undefined at the first time, so in my vue.js component, I see the first map' data but not the cutOff. if I refresh the page I see the cutoff... I don't understand the reason, I tried to rewrite this code but without success, seems that the function doesn't wait for my second map that is a supplier details call.

```
    groupedProducts() {
            const filteredProduct = _.chain(this.products)
                .filter((product) =>
                    !this.selectedSupplier ? true : this.selectedSupplier === product.supplier.id
                )
                .groupBy((product) => product.supplier.id)
                .map((group) => {
                    const { supplier } = group[0];

                    return {
                        products: group,
                        supplier,
                        totalProducts: group.length,
                        _id: supplier.id,
                    };
                })
                .value();
        },
```

Comment: `map` does not mutate `filteredProduct`, ... you need to use the value that `map` returns.

Comment: @trincot so i need to print the data of last map? I tried, but the page is blank, i assigned return item to a variable ad i have returned it the end of the function: return result: item; in map func, and return result at the end. No console errors, nothing, but the calls are in status 200

Comment: It is not nice that you update the question with the information provided in an answer... This way you make your question a moving target.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
filteredProduct = filteredProduct.map(async (item) => {
     const fullData = (await SupplierService.get(item._id)).data;
     item.supplier.cutoff = fullData.cutoff;
     return item;
});
return filteredProduct;
```

or simply

```
return filteredProduct.map(async (item) => {
     const fullData = (await SupplierService.get(item._id)).data;
     item.supplier.cutoff = fullData.cutoff;
     return item;
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work, the cutoff is undefined, i updated my answer with this code

Comment: Mantegnous, please don"t update your answer with code provided in an answer.